# How can I change the tab name of my chrome browser via HTML

Tags: html

I'm tryng to create a HTML page and my tab keeps showing the name of the file. How should I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the 'title' tag inside the head of your html:

```
<head>
   <title>Your html title</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<title>` tag, that's what usually gets displayed as the tab name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that you couldn't find out on search engines. You should have looked it up there. It's `<title></title>` btw. Bear this in mind for the next time.